# R - change matrix values based on another matrix indices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(runif(750), nrow = 50, byrow=T)
m2 <- matrix(rep(TRUE,750), nrow = 50, byrow=T)
```

For each `m1` row, I need to find the indices of the two lowest values. Then, I need to use the remaining indices (i.e. not the two lowest values) to assign `FALSE` in `m2`.

It is fairly easy to do for one row:

```
ind <- order(m1[1,], decreasing=FALSE)[1:2]
m2[1,][-ind] <- FALSE
```

Therefore, I can use a loop to do the same for all rows:

```
for (i in 1:dim(m1)[1]){
  
  ind <- order(m1[i,], decreasing=FALSE)[1:2]
  m2[i,][-ind] <- FALSE
  
}
```

However, in my data set this loop runs slower than I would like (since my matrices are quite large - 500000x150000).

Is there any faster, `R` way to achieve the same result without the use of loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `apply` since you have matrix :

```
val <- rep(TRUE, ncol(m1))
m3 <- t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) {val[-order(x)[1:2]] <- FALSE;val}))
```

Comment: Since this was the fastest option for my dataset, I am accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below

```
m2 <- t(apply(m1,1,function(x) x %in% head(sort(x),2)))
```

Comment: maybe the "partial=2" arg for sort could make it faster if the matrixes are really big

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
m2 <- t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) rank(x)<3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dfr(as.data.frame(m1), ~ min_rank(c(...)) < 3)
```